# Python Whoosh multi-field parser dates and strings

Tags: python, search-engine, whoosh

I am building a search engine and would like to concurrently search for strings and dates. In my index `date` is my date field and `name` is my string field:

```
ix = index.open_dir(dirname)
schema = ix.schema

mp = qparser.MultifieldParser(['date', 'name'], schema, group = og, termclass=FuzzyTerm)

# Add the DateParserPlugin to the parser
mp.add_plugin(DateParserPlugin(free=True))
```

The examples for date-searching in the Whoosh documentation include the date-field as a prefix to a date search like:

```
q = qp.parse(u"date:2005062401")
```

How should dates be parsed, in conjunction with strings, in a multi-field query? Is the string field to be separated from the date like the below example?

```
q = qp.parse(u"date:2005062401, name:tom")
```

I could not find an answer to this question in the documentation, hence my asking here.

References: https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dates.html